# Hostname wildcard % does not include localhost or 127.0.0.0

Tags: windows, mariadb, localhost, database-administration

In MariaDB on windows I create a user and database with the following

```
flush privileges;
CREATE USER 'test-one'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test-one';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test-one'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test-one`;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test-one`.* TO 'test-one'@'%';
```

After that I am unable to connect to the database

```
.\mysql.exe -u "test-one" -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test-one'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Similar behaviour for

```
.\mysql.exe -u "test-one" -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

What does work is (replace  with the actual hostname)
    .\mysql.exe -u "test-one" -p -h

Is this by design? The hostname wildcard '%' does not include localhost nor 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true as long as [anonymous users](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/#anonymous-accounts) exist in the database. When you remove those users, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` start matching the wildcards.

From the [MariaDB Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-user/#host-name-component):

> Note that the credentials added when creating a user with the '%'
>   wildcard host will not grant access in all cases. For example, some
>   systems come with an anonymous localhost user, and when connecting
>   from localhost this will take precedence.

These anonymous users can also be removed when the `mysql_secure_installation` script is run:

> By default, a MariaDB installation has an anonymous user, allowing
>   anyone to log into MariaDB without having to have a user account
>   created for them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the
>   installation go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving
>   into a production environment.
>
> Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]

Comment: Such anonymous user accounts are possibly there to slow down hackers?

Comment: I guess it's possible but if I recall correctly those are removed by `mysql_secure_installation`. I can't really say what the true purpose of those users was originally but to me personally they seem to be a point of confusion most of the time.